# Typescript type to error on intersection of properties

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type which will error if the same property is defined as in another type.  This is to build a type safe merge (perhaps there already is one?)  The following works but I'm wondering if there's a better approach?  Will there be edge cases here that the implementation doesn't handle?

```
type UniqueObject<T extends {[K in keyof U]?: any}, U> = {[K in keyof U]: undefined extends T[K] ? U[K]: never}
function safeMerge <T, U, V, W> (a: T, b?: UniqueObject<T, U>, c?: UniqueObject<T & U, V>, d?: UniqueObject<T & U & V, W>) {
  return { ...a, ...b, ...c, ...d /* etc */ }
}
safeMerge({ ar: 1 }, { ar: 2 })                     // errors correctly
safeMerge({ ar: 1 }, { ar: undefined })             // errors correctly
safeMerge({ ar: 1 }, { b: 2 })                      // works correctly
safeMerge({ ar: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { ar: 3 })           // errors correctly
safeMerge({ ar: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: undefined })    // errors correctly
safeMerge({ ar: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 })            // works correctly
safeMerge({ ar: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { ar: 1 }) // errors correctly
safeMerge({ ar: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { d: 4 })  // works correctly
```

I think the mathematical description of this is a [set difference (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement).

Comment: Looks good. There isn't a better way that is currently supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A safe merge like that doesn't exist in the [native utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), and while some of similar types might exist in libs such as [piotrwitek/utility-types](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types), I didn't see any implementing this type.

Also, as the spread operator only copies ["own enumerable properties"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), you should be safe with that implementation.